# is such tool available in Xcode

Tags: xcode

ALL,

I'm new to Xcode so please bear with me...

In Windows with MSVC there is a tool where I can grab a pointer hover over the window and the tool will display the information about the window: HWND, position and window class.

Is there such a tool in OSX/Xcode?

I am developing a program and for some unknown reason I see a window that should be hidden. I want to check what type of window that is?

TIA!

P.S.: If this question belongs to the Mac forum - I apologize.

P.S.: I'm talking about Spy++ analog for Xcode on OSX.